# Representing ordered sequence as a vector

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

What is the best way to represent a bunch of ordered sequence as a vector in a d-dimensional space?
Imagine we have some ordered sequences like this:

```
abcdefg  
gfabedc
dgdabc  
acbdfer  
abcd
```

and we want to represent them as points in a space so that sequences like the first two (`abcdefg` and `gfabedc`) don't count as one point and we want to compare the sequences by their distance in the space and we want two diverse sequences to have more distance than two similar sequences.